# Is there a way to supply a boolean statement in the isActive parameter within NavigationLink in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to get a `NavigationLink` to trigger when a string is no longer nil. Is there anyway to do this or something similar?

```
NavigationLink(destination: MainView(), isActive: $settings.isLoggedS !=nil)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure about your intention... Triggering `isActive` navigates to link automatically, ie. user won't be needed to click on it... so "Click here after sign in!" looks have no sense.

Comment: @Asperi I originally had it as a button, but now I'm trying to do it programmatically and that text was left over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can program the link.

```
          @State var activeString : String = ""
          var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                NavigationLink(destination: Text(""), isActive: Binding<Bool>(get: {self.activeString != ""}, set: { _ in
                }) ){
                    TextField("input", text: $activeString)}}}
```